# posix sh: is it possible to iterate through a string without using an external tool?

Tags: shell, sh, posix

In POSIX sh, I am able to iterate through each character in a string using a while loop and cut; here is a demonstration:

```
#!/bin/sh

lizards='geckos,anoles'

string_length="${#lizards}"

i=1
while [ "$i" -le "$string_length" ]; do
    char="$(echo "$lizards" | cut -c "$i")"
    echo "$char"
    i="$(( i + 1 ))"
done
```

Output is:

```
g
e
c
k
o
s
,
a
n
o
l
e
s
```

Is there a way I can do without this having to call an external command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `printf` to get the first character and parameter expansion to remove it:

```
#!/bin/sh

lizards='geckos,anoles'

while [ -n "$lizards" ]; do
    printf '%.1s\n' "$lizards"
    lizards="${lizards#?}"
done
```

Comment: Very elegant solution, but if you want to save the 'lizards' variable for later use you would probably want to add 'iterate_characters="$lizards"' and then change all instances of 'lizards' to 'iterate_characters' in the while block

Answer (score 1):

You can easily reduce the number of external commands from one per character to one for the whole string by using `fold` instead of `cut`:

```
#!/bin/sh

lizards='geckos,anoles'

echo "$lizards" | fold -w 1
```

I can't think of a good way to do it purely with builtins. But I did think of an ugly way:

```
#!/bin/sh

lizards='geckos,anoles'

string_length="${#lizards}"

# Initialize j to length string_length-1 filled with ?'s and k to empty
i=1
j=
k=
while [ "$i" -lt "$string_length" ]; do
    j="?$j"
    i="$(( i + 1 ))"
done

i=0
# From here on, j contains string_length-i-1 ?'s and k contains i ?'s
while [ "$i" -lt "$string_length" ]; do
    char="${lizards#$k}"
    char="${char%$j}"
    echo "$char" # or printf '%c\n' "$char"
    j="${j#?}"
    k="?$k"
    i="$(( i + 1 ))"
done
```

To understand it, you must first understand the `${var#pattern}` and `${var%pattern}` expansions, which compare the beginning (`#`) or end (`%`) of `$var` to the pattern (glob-like, not regexp) and remove the matched portion. (These take the shortest match, `##` and `%%` take the longest match, but that doesn't matter here.)

So if I want `$var` with the first 2 characters removed, I use `${var#??}`. If I want the last 2 characters removed, I use `${var%??}`. So I make a loop, using a variable number of `?` to trim both ends each time. Basically it does this:

```
char=${lizards#}; char=${char%????????????}; echo $char
char=${lizards#?}; char=${char%???????????}; echo $char
char=${lizards#??}; char=${char%??????????}; echo $char
char=${lizards#???}; char=${char%?????????}; echo $char
char=${lizards#????}; char=${char%????????}; echo $char
char=${lizards#?????}; char=${char%???????}; echo $char
char=${lizards#??????}; char=${char%??????}; echo $char
char=${lizards#???????}; char=${char%?????}; echo $char
char=${lizards#????????}; char=${char%????}; echo $char
char=${lizards#?????????}; char=${char%???}; echo $char
char=${lizards#??????????}; char=${char%??}; echo $char
char=${lizards#???????????}; char=${char%?}; echo $char
char=${lizards#????????????}; char=${char%}; echo $char
```

I particularly enjoyed writing the line `j="${j#?}"` which uses the `${var#pattern}` construction to remove a character from a variable that will be used as the pattern in the next `${var%pattern}` construction.

In reality, I think I'd use `fold`.

Answer (score 1):

From some years back here's a similar *POSIX* method to [*that other guy*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49698813/6136214), which instead of `printf` relies on more variables, (too many?) and requires both *Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern* (`${parameter%word}`) and *Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern* (`${parameter#word}`) parameter expansions:

```
splitchar(){ unset r c
             q="$1"
             while [ "$q" ]; do  
                 s="$q" q="${q#?}" c="${s%$q}" r="$r$c
"
             done
             echo "${r%?}"; }
```

Example:

```
splitchar hello
```

Output:

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

Comment: Hmm.  Actually it's more like [*WQW*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49698690/6136214), but without the `$i` counter...